# Changing permalink structure breaks link to .php file which generates files dynamically

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks

I'm creating a (calendar) plugin where one feature is the ability to download an event as a .ics-file. To do that I have a file called ics.php in which I generate an .ics-file based on the id of the event, passed by a querystring. So far everything works.

```
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=event.ics');
// output...
```

However, after changing permalink structure from the default to month and name, everytime the file is generated the browser can't find it. (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in Chrome, and "File not found" in Firefox).

I can access ics.php but when I add the id of the event to be parsed (ics.php?e=5) I get the above mentioned error. I want the users to be able to use any kind of permalink structure with the plugin, so I need a solution to this.

Maybe worth mentioning is that the events are stored as custom post types.

Comment: how are you calling the file from your plugin? how do you load the WordPress environment from your plugin file if it's called directly?

Comment: I link to it directly: ics.php?e=5 , where 5 is the id of the event. I was including wp-blog-header.php which usually works, but after your comment I changed it to wp-load.php and now it seems to be working. I need to read up on why, but it's working for now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was bootstrapping Wordpress in ics.php by including wp-blog-header.php (which usually works for me), but after changing it to include wp-load.php instead, the files generated were no longer not being found.